# Issues with running keras model in docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow, keras

I wrote a python script for a keras model which uses tensorflow as backend. I tried to run this model in docker. But when I ran it, it always showed "killed". Is this because of a memory issue that my docker doesn't have that much of space to run my python script? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
I checked my python script and it ran well in other environments. 
The data I use to feed the model is very big. When I use a smaller-size data, the model works in the container. Any suggestions on how to use the large data set?

This is my dockerfile that I used to build up the image:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install sklearn
RUN pip install matplotlib
RUN pip install keras
RUN pip install tensorflow

RUN mkdir app
COPY . /app

CMD ["python", “app/model2-keras-model.py”]
```

when I ran it in the container, this is what I got:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: are you sure your code and model run correctly, no memory or other issues (for example did you run it in other environment than docker image)?

Comment: My code runs well in other environment

Comment: some resource is not loaded or is not enough this is what i gather, try to use another docker image or different settings. maybe it will work

Comment: Thank you Nikos. The data I use to feed the model is very big. When I use a smaller-size data, the model works in the container. Any suggestion on how to make the large dataset work?

Comment: how big is 'very big' ?  gigs / terabytes / hundreds tbs / pbs ?